# Two google maps on single page with different id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

i am totaly new to google map api and i dont know much about how it will be  configured to display two maps .  i am using a map for displaying the near by schools and the clients requirements are displaying 3 maps in single page on different locations with different data on each map . the problem here is that when ever i put a new map div and change script it wont show up . changed id not displaying , change init in in script loading =places&callback=initMap  not displaying changed js dont work again . my js code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var infowindow;
function initMap() {
  var pyrmont = {lat: <?= $data->latitude ?>, lng: <?= $data->longitude ?>};
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 1500,
    type: ['school']
  }, schoolCallback);


}
function schoolCallback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createSchoolMarker(results[i]); //results doesn't contain anything related to type (school,store,etc)
    }
  }
}
function createSchoolMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/16/Science-School-icon.png",
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

HTML code is

```
<div class="resultmap" style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="map3" style="width: 100%; height: 316px;"></div>
  </div>
```

any one have developed a page with multiple maps please suggest a suitable approach

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you wrap all the javascript map code into a function that accepts the id of the div element. After that go have three div elements each with a unique id. Then call the function three times.

```
<!-- each of the following will hold a map -->
<div id="map1"></div>
<div id="map2"></div>
<div id="map3"></div>

//wrap the javascript code for the map in a function
function makeMap("whichMap"){
  //the following will be the line that selects the div
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(whichMap), {
}
```